# Hibernate inner join across databases

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I have 1 table in my database (`instance_main`) that I need to inner join on in another database (`instance_core`). Typically I would use something like this.

```
SELECT
instance_core.cnm.MenuID,
instance_core.cnm.NavigationID,
instance_core.cnm.StackView,
instance_core.cnm.StackClass,
instance_core.cnm.IsAdmin
FROM
instance_core.CoreNavigationMenu cnm
INNER JOIN instance_main.ACLGroupPermissions gp ON instance_core.cnm.MenuID = instance_main.gp.MenuID
WHERE instance_main.gp.GroupID = 1
```

I do not have a many-to-many relationship from `ACLGroupPermissions` to `CoreNavigationMenu`.

So far I have tried this, but it always returns a null result. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

```
@Override
public List<CoreNavigationMenu> getPermissions(AclGroup dataObject) {

    List<CoreNavigationMenu> aclList = template.find("FROM CoreNavigationMenu cnm inner join ACLGroupPermissions agp on cnm.MenuID = agp.MenuID WHERE agp.GroupID = ?",dataObject.getGroupId());        
    
    return aclList;
}
```

My `ACLGroupPermissions` entity looks like this: [`ACLGroupPermission` Entity](http://pastebin.com/DbuixhSE)

My `CoreNavigationMenu` entity looks like this: [`CoreNavigationMenu` Entity](http://pastebin.com/2PCQfiDg)

Comment: You can not do it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552330/doing-a-join-over-2-tables-in-different-databases-using-hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed with Adi's comment - this cannot be done, per the reasons mentioned at [Doing a join over 2 tables in different databases using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552330/doing-a-join-over-2-tables-in-different-databases-using-hibernate).

(Primarily posting this answer in an attempt to either get this question some additional attention / competitive answers, or at the least, to simply remove this from the growing list of unanswered questions.)