# Join 2 table in Java using two different connections

Tags: java, database, hibernate, join

I have a problem. I have to do a join between 2 tables on 2 different database. I can not use the dblink. The only solution is a join in Java using two different connections. 
My question is: In Hibernate you can do this?

In Java there are frameworks that allow me to do a join between two tables in two different databases?

Comment: Have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552330/doing-a-join-over-2-tables-in-different-databases-using-hibernate

Comment: Mmmm.. Then in Hibernate isn't possible. Other solution?

Comment: Your only option is that your database platform supports it. For example Oracle does supports JOINs over dblinks which can point to different database. But there is a bunch of issues that comes with it, performace at the first place..